# Add partition to table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have created a table and trying to add a partition on it but it is failing with the error invalid datatype.

```
drop table test;
create table test (id number , h_date date);

ALTER TABLE TEST ADD  PARTITION BY RANGE ("h_date") INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(PARTITION "P20120101"  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2012-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')))                                                                                                            
PARALLEL 4                                                                                                              
PCTFREE 10;
```

error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
```

Is something wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You created a "normal" table, however you must create a Partitioned Table, see these examples [Creating Partitions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm#BAJHFFBE)

Comment: yes but i want to add the partition to a normal table.

Comment: Yes, but this is not possible unless you make a [redefinition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042). However, redefinition means basically you create a new table, copy the data from the old to the new table and drop the old table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Wernfried Domscheit pointed out you need to redefine your table. For an existing and data-populated table the following block might be referenced as a method :

```
SQL> create table test(id number , h_date date);     
Table created

SQL> insert all
  2         into test values(1,date'2011-12-31')
  3         into test values(1,date'2012-01-01')
  4         into test values(1,date'2012-01-02')
  5  select * from dual;     
3 rows inserted

SQL> select *
  2    from test;     
        ID H_DATE
---------- -----------
         1 31.12.2011
         1 01.01.2012
         1 02.01.2012

SQL> create table test2
  2    partition by range(h_date)
  3    interval
  4   (numtodsinterval(1,'day'))
  5   (partition "P20120101" values less than(to_date('2012-01-01 00:00:00', 
                             'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')))
  6  as
  7  select * from test;     
Table created

SQL> select *
  2    from test2
  3     partition("P20120101");     
        ID H_DATE
---------- -----------
         1 31.12.2011

SQL> drop table test;
Table dropped

SQL> rename test2 to test;
Table renamed
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Barbaros you cannot add partition to a non-partitioned table.

However, there are several ways to transform a non-partitioned table into a partitioned table.

- Create a new partitioned table, copy all data from existing table to this new table, drop the old one. See answer from Barbaros to get an example.
- Use the [DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042) package. It is more than just a single command, go to the documentation to get more details or ask specific question here if you have one.
- In Oracle version 12.2 the feature [Online Conversion of a Nonpartitioned Table to a Partitioned Table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/newft/new-features.html#GUID-D5D9C311-3597-4494-B8DE-CE33EE4FA546) was introduced. With this feature it would be a simple command:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE test MODIFY
  PARTITION BY RANGE (h_date) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' DAY) (
      PARTITION P20120101 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2012-01-01')
  ) ONLINE;
  ```

Perhaps you are looking for [Exchanging Partitions and Subpartitions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-E08650B4-06B1-43F9-91B0-FBF685A3B848.htm#VLDBG1156). With this function you can convert a non-partitioned table to a partition of another (partitioned) table, or vice versa.